# How long will it take for 3000 ants growing at 6% to overtake 4500 ants growing at 4%

Tags: calculus

So the problem is that Grey ants grow at 4% per year and Red ants at 6% per year. How long will it take for 3000 Red ants to over take 6000 Grey ants.

$Growth = A \times  e^{rate \times time}$

$Growth(r) = 3000 \times  e^{1.06 \times time}$ and $Growth(g) = 4500 \times  e^{1.04 \times time}$

So I want to find t when G(r) = G(g)

So I did this

$3000 \times  e^{1.06 \times time} = 4500 \times  e^{1.04 \times time}$

$e^{1.06 \times time}/e^{1.04 \times time} = 4500/3000 $

$(1.06)t/(1.04)t = ln(4500/3000) $

And I'm stuck here, the t's cancel each other out

Comment: Review your laws of logarithms. In particular, $\log \frac{a}{b} \neq \frac{ \log a } {\log b}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{1.06 \times time}/e^{1.04 \times time} = 4500/3000 $$ 
$$e^{1.06 \times time - 1.04 \times time} = 4500/3000 $$
$$e^{0.02 \times time} = 4500/3000 $$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We need $$3000\left(1+\frac6{100}\right)^n> 4500\left(1+\frac4{100}\right)^n$$

$$\implies \left(\frac{53}{52}\right)^n>\frac{4500}{3000}=\frac32$$

Now we need to use logarithm

Comment: What happened to e?

Comment: @Ghozt, I think you need this formula : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound_Interest

Comment: So i dont want continuos growth which I would use e for, I just want simple growth and then work out the time it takes for it to be greater